# Hibernate sqlite SQLITE_BUSY

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I am trying to use hibernate with sqlite in multi-threaded application and getting SQLITE_BUSY error:

```
[SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
```

Simplified code which reproduces error in 1 thread:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(new Object());
session.flush();

Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
session2.beginTransaction();
session2.save(new Object());
session2.getTransaction().commit();
```

As widely suggested i set pool_size to 1, but it didn't help

```
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
```

packages that i use:

```
sqlite-jdbc: 3.8.7
hibernate: 4.3.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom connection pool hibernate-c3p0 did the job.
Just add to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And to hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1</property>
```

Comment: Looked good, but got an Exception: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0MessageLogger.connectionProperties(Ljava/util/Properties;)V
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at nl.deholtmans.HibernateHelloWorld.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
 at nl.deholtmans.HibernateHelloWorld.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
 at nl.deholtmans.HibernateHelloWorld.OneToManyExampleStockData.main(OneToManyExampleStockData.java:17)

Comment: I have done this as well - and the whole thing just freezes when it tries to execute a query...